# How interpret BGP message gerated by libbgpdump?

Tags: bgp

I download a bgp archive from routeviews website. I get as this line:

```
BGP4MP|1378027817|A|202.249.2.86|7500|41.191.103.0/24|7500 2518 2914 1273 36994 37672 37089|IGP|202.249.2.86|0|0||NAG||
```

Can you help me to interpret this line? I don't know who announce the prefix : AS7500 or AS37089?

Thanks.

Comment: What is libbgpdump, and where did you do this?

Comment: as Vink said, you can download the libbgpdump at https://bitbucket.org/ripencc/bgpdump/wiki/Home. for archives that contains BGP data, you can find these archive in the routeviews websiten, for example: in http://archive.routeviews.org/route-views.nwax/bgpdata/2014.03/UPDATES/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those unfamiliar with libbgpdump: it's a library for analysing dump files generated by Zebra/Quagga and MRT. It's maintained by RIPE NCC: https://bitbucket.org/ripencc/bgpdump/wiki/Home.

The AS-path recorded is `7500 2518 2914 1273 36994 37672 37089`. So AS37089 *originated* the prefix, AS7500 *announced* it to the router on which the dump was generated.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this is the output format of bgpdump.

```
|timestamp|A/W|peer-ip|peer-asn|prefix|as-path|origin-protocol|next-hop|local-pref|MED|communities|atomic aggregator|aggregator field|
```

Posting this, because the wiki does not seem to be available anymore. 
On a side note, consider using https://github.com/CAIDA/libbgpstream, as it is still maintained and offers automatic download of RIPE RIS and Route-views route collector data.